# How to get an object into localStorage by key in order to get properties(mark, model) an object?

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage, webstorm

```
let listValue = [
    {
        key: '1',
        value: {
            mark: 'Audi',
            model: 'A1',
        }
    },

    {
        key: '2',
        value: {
            mark: 'Audi',
            model: 'TT',
        }
    }

];

localStorage.setItem('listValue', JSON.stringify(listValue));
let carObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('1'));
document.getElementById("new2").innerHTML = carObj.mark;
```

Comment: You are setting with item with key 'listValue' and fetching by key '1' ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the item from `localStorage` using the same name "listValue": `localStorage.getItem('listValue')`.

And then, to get the car by the string `key` from the array `listValue` you can make a [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example).

Check a working demo at: https://jsfiddle.net/yosvelquintero/vanus5ah/1/

Code:

```
let listValue = [{
  key: '1',
  value: {
    mark: 'Audi',
    model: 'A1',
  }
}, {
  key: '2',
  value: {
    mark: 'Audi',
    model: 'TT',
  }
}];

localStorage.setItem('listValue', JSON.stringify(listValue));

let carObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listValue'));

// Find the car by key '1'
let car = carObj.find((c) => c.key === '1');

document.getElementById('new2').innerHTML = car.value.mark;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your codes like this :

```
let listValue = [
{
    key: '1',
    value: {
        mark: 'Audi',
        model: 'A1',
    }
},

{
    key: '2',
    value: {
        mark: 'Audi',
        model: 'TT',
    }
}

];

localStorage.setItem('listValue', JSON.stringify(listValue));
var carObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listValue'));

for (var i=0; i<=carObj.length -1; i++){     
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " " + carObj[i].value.mark;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/58pq114n/1/